# Matlab_max value in each col

Tags: matlab

I have this matrix

```
v=[4,-2,1;-2,1,-1;-2,3,6]
```

How can i return the max value of specific col with its row index ? Knowing that i used this function :

```
[amax,rowIdx]=max(abs(v(k:n,k)),[],1)
```

but it doesn't work well

> here is my code :

---

---

---

---

> ```
> v=[4,-2,1;-2,1,-1;-2,3,6]
> n=3;
> for k=1:n-1
>    [amax,rowIdx]=max(abs(v(k:n,k)),[],1)
> end
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get maximum of third column?

```
[max_val, max_idx] = max(v(:, 3));
```

you select the third column from the matrix -> that gives you a single vector. max then operates on this vector and returns the max value together with its position, which is the row index in the original matrix.